# SageTeX for posets

Tags: sagetex

One can use SAGE to get a LaTeX output for posets. For example entering

```
u=posets.BooleanLattice(4)

print(display(u),print(latex(u)))
```

in the sage cell (https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) will display the poset u and then give a TikZ output to obtain it in LaTeX.

Now in SAGE the points of a poset with n points are enumerated from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n.

> Question: Is there an easy way to get the LaTeX output where the points are enumerated by 1 to n (by setting i->i+1 in the SAGE graphic)?

Of course one can do this by hand for a given example, but for big posets it would be better to have an automatic way of doing this (via SAGE?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/posets/posets.html#sage.combinat.posets.posets.FinitePoset.relabel) on poset documentation, you just need to use `relabel()` to change the vertices. SAGE takes care of the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
u=posets.BooleanLattice(4)
output = latex(u)

Q = u.relabel(lambda x: x+1)
output2 = latex(Q)
\end{sagesilent}
The original poset in SAGE is this:

\begin{center}
\sagestr{output}
\end{center}

After relabelling the vertices, it now looks like this:

\begin{center}
\sagestr{output2}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output running in Cocalc is:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you compile the code output by `latex(u)` after doing `u = posets.BooleanLattice(4)` in Sage. In this case, you can use [expsagetex](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex) to retrieve this LaTeX (actually, Ti*k*Z) code and store it in a macro (here: a `tl` variable). Then, it's a bit of a hack, but you can use `l3regex` to (sort of) replace every occurrence of `L=\hbox{$〈number〉$}` with `L=\mbox{$〈number+1〉$}` in the retrieved code:

```latex
% document.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expsagetex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__mare_diagram_code_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mare_diagram_ID_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \myInsertDiagram { m }
  {
    \est_record_formatted:Nn \l__mare_diagram_ID_tl {#1}
    \est_refused:V \l__mare_diagram_ID_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__mare_diagram_code_tl
      { \est_get:Vnn \l__mare_diagram_ID_tl {??} { \emph{paused} } }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { L\ *\=\ *\c{hbox} \cB\{ \cM\$ (\d+) \cM\$ \cE\} }
      { L\=\c{mbox} \cB\{ \cM\$ \c{int_eval:n} \cB\{ \1 + 1 \cE\} \cM\$ \cE\} }
      \l__mare_diagram_code_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__mare_diagram_code_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% The default output at scale=1 has many overlapping nodes
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={scale=2}}
\myInsertDiagram{posets.BooleanLattice(4)}

\end{document}
```

Run for instance `pdflatex document.tex`, then `sage document.sagetex.sage`, then again `pdflatex document.tex` and you'll obtain:

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a solution yet. In poset, the positioning of the vertices is important, as this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) explains. In the diagram you'll see: "Distinct sets on the same horizontal level are incomparable with each other."

Comment: @DJP Well, this layout is not the responsibility of my code. It is how  `tkz-graph` formats the result of `latex()` called on the `posets.BooleanLattice(4)` object. I'm afraid that is where you should direct your complaints...